# Chef: Why are resources in an "include_recipe" step being skipped?

Tags: provisioning, chef-infra, vagrant

Chef seems to be processing resources in a strange order, causing my build to fail. My main recipe (`mytardis-chef/site-cookbooks/recipes/default.rb`) starts like this:

```
include_recipe "build-essential"
include_recipe "mytardis::deps"
include_recipe "mytardis::nginx"
include_recipe "mytardis::postgresql"
```

`mytardis-chef/cookbooks/build-essential/recipes/default.rb` looks like this:

```
case node['platform']
when "ubuntu","debian"
  %w{build-essential binutils-doc}.each do |pkg|
    package pkg do
      action :install
    end
  end
when "centos","redhat","fedora","scientific"
  %w{gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel make}.each do |pkg|
    package pkg do
      action :install
    end
  end
end
```

... (it's an older version of `https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential/blob/master/recipes/default.rb`)

At runtime, for reasons I don't understand, this build-essential recipe gets loaded but not executed:

```
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[default] -- v-csr-3: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-3/roles
[default] -- v-csc-2: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/cookbooks
[default] -- v-csc-1: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
[default] -- v-csdb-4: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-4/data_bags
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefSolo...
[default] Generating chef JSON and uploading...
[default] Running chef-solo...
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] INFO: *** Chef 10.12.0 ***
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] DEBUG: Building node object for lucid32
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] DEBUG: Extracting run list from JSON attributes provided on command line
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[mytardis]"] from JSON
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] DEBUG: Applying attributes from json file
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] DEBUG: Platform is ubuntu version 10.04
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] INFO: Run List is [recipe[mytardis]]
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] INFO: Run List expands to [mytardis]
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] INFO: Starting Chef Run for lucid32
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] INFO: Running start handlers
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:32 +0200] INFO: Start handlers complete.
...
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe mytardis via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe default in cookbook mytardis
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe build-essential via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe default in cookbook build-essential
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe mytardis::deps via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe deps in cookbook mytardis
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe mytardis::nginx via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe nginx in cookbook mytardis
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe iptables via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe default in cookbook iptables
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe mytardis::postgresql via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe postgresql in cookbook mytardis
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe postgresql::server via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe server in cookbook postgresql
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Loading Recipe postgresql::client via include_recipe
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: Found recipe client in cookbook postgresql
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] INFO: Processing package[postgresql-client] action install (postgresql::client line 37)
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:33 +0200] DEBUG: package[postgresql-client] checking package status for postgresql-client
....
[Sun, 08 Jul 2012 05:14:45 +0200] ERROR: gem_package[pg] (postgresql::client line 42) has had an error
.
make
sh: make: not found
```

That is, the build-essential recipe is "found" and "loaded", but it's the postgres recipe that gets "processed" first. And since build-essential (which installs the C  compiler) wasn't run, the latter fails.

The relevant part of my Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
     chef.log_level = :debug
     chef.cookbooks_path = ["mytardis-chef/site-cookbooks", "mytardis-chef/cookbooks"]
     chef.roles_path = "mytardis-chef/roles"
     chef.data_bags_path = "mytardis-chef/data_bags"
     chef.add_recipe "mytardis"    
  end
```

I was previously using a slightly earlier version of Chef (perhaps 10.10.0?) In that version, build-essential was also not being run, but mytardis::deps was. Now using Chef 10.12.0. Physical machine is OSX, VM is Ubuntu Lucid.

So, a few questions:

1. Why is build-essential not being "processed"?
2. What's the right way to do this? (I didn't write these recipes, and I understand they do or have worked for their author.)
3. Should the site-cookbooks and cookbooks 'shadowing' feature still work? It's supposedly deprecated: http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2308  (I tried making a symbolic link under from site-cookbooks/mytardis/recipes/build-essential but no joy).

Comment: You can put Chef::Log.info("I am in #{cookbook_name}::#{recipe_name}") in build-essential/recipes/default.rb and it will print the log message when it loads the recipe. The file created by the exception handler, something like "/var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json" will also have the entire resource collection of all the resources it loaded, which can aid in debugging whether the resources in the recipe were added.

Comment: The cookbook shadowing feature is that where you can overwrite components that exist in a cookbook by putting them in site-cookbooks, not merely having separate cookbooks in both locations.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It turns out this is a pretty normal (but under-documented) part of how Chef works: it compiles everything, and *then* starts running. Except some recipes (like Postgres) jump the queue to actually install at compile-time, using code like this:

```
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:run)
```

The solution is that anything that needs to run before Postgres also needs to do this. Fortunately, newer versions of [Build-essentials](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/build-essential) allow this. You set attributes on a role as follows:

```
name "myapp"
run_list(
  "recipe[build-essential]",
  "recipe[myapp]"
)
default_attributes(
  "build_essential" => {
    "compiletime" => true
  }
)
```

Comment: I ran into this today with another cookbook which depends on `database::postgresql`, which in turn depends on `postgresql::ruby`.  The current recipe for `postgresql::ruby` installs the `pg` gem, `libpq`, and `postgresql` all at the **Compilation** phase of the Chef run.  It does this by using `run_action(:install)` as this answer points out.

Comment: There is another way to work around this in certain cases... for example:  Running `kitchen test` on a cookbook which includes `postgresql::ruby` can result in apt errors from a stale package cache.  To fix this, we can use the `now` cookbook's DSL to force an `apt-get update` at the beginning of the Chef run like this:  `include_recipe_now 'apt'`

Answer (score 6):

if writing a cookbook, add the attribute to your attributes file:

```
node.default['build_essential']['compiletime'] = true
```

Thanks to Colin above.

Comment: Is that specific to the build_essential recipe, or does that work anywhere? Is it documented?

Comment: Steve, that syntax is usable in any recipe. node is the 'self' reference of a Chef Node, default is the self-titled setting that gets applied on the cookbook / recipe use, unless overrided again. The other two options are build_essential specific.