# Chef: Trying to get build-essential to install on our node before Postgres

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Here's our node configuration:

```
{
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[apt]",
    "recipe[build-essential]",
    [
      "rackbox"
    ]
  ],
  "rackbox": {
    "jenkins": {
      "job": "job1",
      "git_repo": "https://github.com/hayesmp/railsgirls-app.git",
      "command": "bundle exec rake",
      "ip_address": "192.237.181.154",
      "host": "subocean-southerner"
    },
    "ruby": {
      "versions": [
        "2.0.0-p247"
      ],
      "global_version": "2.0.0-p247"
    },
    "apps": {
      "unicorn": [
        {
          "appname": "app1",
          "hostname": "app1"
        }
      ]
    },
    "db_root_password": "iloverandompasswordsbutthiswilldo",
    "databases": {
      "postgresql": [
        {
          "database_name": "app1_production",
          "username": "app1",
          "password": "app1_pass"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm just not sure where to insert the build essential compiletime = true attribute for my configuration.

This is the sample code for this stack overflow post: [Chef: Why are resources in an "include_recipe" step being skipped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380485/chef-why-are-resources-in-an-include-recipe-step-being-skipped)

```
name "myapp"
run_list(
  "recipe[build-essential]",
  "recipe[myapp]"
)
default_attributes(
  "build_essential" => {
    "compiletime" => true
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this into your node configuration:

```
"build_essential": {
    "compiletime": true
}
```

BTW: you should use `recipe[rackbox]` instead of `[rackbox]` in your `run_list`

Comment: It's still trying to run the postgres install before build essential. The only way I've gotten it to work is to add `apt-get -y install build-essential` to the top of my default recipe.