# Chef: last recipe in run list seems to be run first

Tags: ruby, list, chef-infra

I have this run list: `recipe-A, my-recipe`.

`recipe-A` creates `/etc/A` directory.

`my-recipe` has these codes:

```
...
// create '/etc/A/file-1'
...
File.symlink('/etc/A/file-1', '/etc/A/file-2')
...
```

So, when `my-recipe` runs, there should be `/etc/A` directory already, which was created by `recipe-A`. But I got this error at very first of the chef run:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in ...
================================================================================

Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - (/etc/A/file-1, /etc/A/file-2)
```

I am sure that `recipe-A` has not been run when this error message is shown up. But isn't it supposed for `recipe-A` to run first? Why is Chef checking the existence of `/etc/A`, which is created by `recipe-A` while it has not been run? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run it as ruby code, use the [link](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_link.html) resource to create the symlink.

```
link "/etc/A/file-2" do
  to "/etc/A/file-1"
end
```

I'm pretty sure that your Ruby code is already executed during the [compilation phase](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html) of the chef run, that's why the code from the second recipe seems to be executed first.

Comment: This works great! Actually it is `link "...file-2" do to "...file-1" end` but I got the idea of using this link resource. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, there is [another topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380485/chef-why-are-resources-in-an-include-recipe-step-being-skipped) which has the answer explaining the cause of this "disrespect" of run order. Chef definitely needs better documentation.